# Access OpenAI (json) API from R

Tags: r, json, curl, openai-api, gpt-3

I want to access the OpenAI API with the following curl command from R:

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_KEY" \
-d '{"prompt": "This is a test", "max_tokens": 5}'
```

I think the curl package (on CRAN) will be the best option(?). I have never used this package so can anyone help me getting started with this simple call?

Comment: Try `httr::GET(myurl, query=list(prompt="This is a test", max_tokens=5), httr::add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", apikey)))` (replacing the two refs).

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html

Comment: @r2evans: Thank you, unfortunately I get the following strange response: 
`Response [https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions?prompt=This%20is%20a%20test&max_tokens=5]
  Date: 2021-05-03 18:39
  Status: 405
  Content-Type: application/json
  Size: 225 B
{
  "error": {
    "code": null,
    "message": "Not allowed to GET on /v1/engines/davinci/completions. (HINT: Perhaps you meant to use a different HTTP method?)",
    "param": null,
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}`

Comment: You can try the [POST](https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create) method, try `httr::POST` instead. (I don't have an API key, so it's difficult for me to do more than suggest `httr::` command variants.)

Comment: @r2evans: I know, but I am not allowed to give you the key :-( How would I set up the POST method exactly?

Comment: Still https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html, though perhaps with `body=` instead of `query=`.

Comment: @r2evans: Now it worked... see my answer below... thank you very much!!

Comment: `https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an R package named "openapi" (https://github.com/zhanghao-njmu/openapi), which supports all OpenAI APIs and can generate streaming returns (currently, other packages do not have good solutions), chatGPT app, and various RStudio add-ins. Welcome to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done with the `httr` package (on CRAN), hat tip to @r2evans:

```
library(httr)
myurl <- "https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci/completions"
apikey <- "YOUR_API_KEY"
seed_text <- "This is a test"
tokens <- 5
output <- POST(myurl, body = list(prompt = seed_text, max_tokens = tokens), add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", apikey)), encode = "json")
content(output)$choices[[1]]$text
## [1] " of a national emergency communication"
```

Comment: Since they have python examples in their code, you might suggest offering this as another language alternative for access. Glad you got it to work!